# Using SharePoint 2010 webparts in a classic .net asp application

Tags: .net, sharepoint

Does anyone have an experience using SP2010 Web Parts in a classic aspx application, assuming you would reference sharepoint dlls? I am referring specifically to the search center web parts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

2010 even :) I dont think anyone has this experience.. it's only in public beta for a few weeks!

I also don't think it is possible.. my guess is SharePoint web parts will only run within the SharePoint context, e.g. a SharePoint web application.